# DISTINCT ON with Ruby on Rails and Arel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arel

I have the following table structure (simplified)

```
id | version | slug |     state
-------------------------------
 1 |       1 |    A | published
 2 |       2 |    A |     draft
 3 |       1 |    B | published
 4 |       1 |    C | published
 4 |       2 |    C | published
 4 |       3 |    C |     draft
```

I want to get all records with the highest version number, grouped by slug and where the state is published. The SQL for this looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(slug) *
FROM guides
WHERE state = 'published'
ORDER BY slug ASC, version DESC;
```

And packed into Rails:

```
Klass.select('DISTINCT ON(slug) *').where(state: :published).order(slug: :asc, version: :desc)
```

Is there any nicer syntax available? In the past I used a bit of Arel, but I don't seem to get the distinct part correct.

Answer (score -1):

The AR query is already quite nice and simple. I don't think you can get anything different and I don't see anything wrong with it.

The only thing you can change is to use `DISTINCT(slug)` rather than `DISTINCT ON(slug) *`.

Comment: `DISTINCT(slug)` behaves like `DISTINCT slug` which is not the same as `DISTINCT ON (slug) *`!